# Congratulations to Joe Strazzere for 100k rep!

Tags: discussion

Joe is one of our most consistent and prolific contributors here in the community.  He is always polite, thoughtful and helpful.  In my brief time here in this wonderful community, I can always be assured that if Joe has given an answer, then it is worth taking the time to read.

So it was no surprise to me to see he has earned the recognition by the community for his efforts and has achieved the milestone of 100k reputation.

[image: Joe Strazzere]

Please join me in congratulating Joe for his impressive contribution to the community!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere :)

Comment: Joe, congratulations on this achievement and thanks for helping to make The Workplace great!

Comment: Thank you - that was very nice. What a neat post to wake up and read!

Comment: @joestrazzere I saw your rep at 99,999 and thought "Well, we can't let _that_ go unmarked!" :)

Comment: Congratulations @JoeStrazzere, thanks for both your contributions on the main site, as well as your help in guiding the direction of our site here on meta!

Comment: Does **Jane S** means Jane Strazzere? Uhmm... I just want to know. I am not assuming. :)

Comment: @CaryBondoc LOL! No, my "S" is a different surname.  I'm also in the wrong country.  Actually, I'm on the wrong side of the planet :)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm glad that it's clear to us now. :)

Comment: I remember when I had more rep than Joe. It lasted all of three days. Congratulations @JoeStrazzere! 100k more! 100k more!

Comment: Which begs the question, "Where do you find any time to work?"  :)  Seriously, though, congrats, Joe!

Comment: @WesleyLong (Joe is secretly a conglomerate of HR professionals writing under a pseudonym!)

Comment: Maaaan, Joe, you talk too much. ^_^ Goncrats!

Comment: @JaneS Get ready to prep for Joe's 200K! I estimate it to come around in 3-4 months.

Answer (score 45):

I often find myself wanting to answer a question, only to see an answer from Joe that says what I wanted to say. So I just cast my upvote and wait for the next chance...

You are also the only person with the [Legendary Badge](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary?userid=7777) - this means you have hit the 200 reputation cap 150 times (at least, that was awarded almost a year ago).

Thanks for helping make this place great!

Comment: Yeah can we implement some kind of "Joe can't answer for 30 minutes" rule, to give the rest of us mere mortals a chance? :)

Comment: @JonStory Feature request? ;)

Comment: The Jon Skeet of TWP. Joe Skeetzere.

Comment: @Bmo It is odd that we never see Joe Strazzere and Jon Skeet in the same place...

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations Joe.

As a newbie in this community, I can say that you are an inspiration for people contributing here.

Your answers are a proof that high-scoring and the best answers can indeed be the shortest ones.

Keep going!

Answer (score 6):

Wow! Nice work Joe!  I also and happy to see him here, and always find his answers really excellent.

Answer (score 6):

Congrats Joe. That is some accomplishment. I have been on Stack overflow for 7 years and am nowhere near that!

Comment: I was searching for my answer here and noticed that you now have 100k rep too!

Comment: @ElysianFields The question is why would you want to do that ~1.5 years later? ...

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος, you chose to comment on his comment more than a year later.

Comment: @HLGEM At least I stumbled on this post, not searched for it. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Well done Joe, I've browsed a lot of the older (before I arrived) questions, and I think your answers are well thought out and helpful ones. You definitely earned your laurels.

Answer (score 5):

Joe's answers are always inspiring and sure reflects his ultimate professionalism.

Congratulations for being the first to achieve 100k rep and thanks for your contributions! And may the rest of us follow your example.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments!

Answer (score 4):

I always enjoy Joe's answers. Concise, helpful, informative and I always give myself a pat on the back if I have a "I was going to say that" moment!

He is one of the very best of an exceptionally good community here on The Workplace where the lack of trolls and absence people just wanting to pick fights must be mentioned to. It is a place that fulfills it's brief of being a place people share problems and receive advice.

Please carry on Joe. You would leave a hole bigger than you could imagine if you stopped contributing.

And everyone else. Please keep on being a great community.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I agree - this is a great community.