# Congratulations to enderland for your Legendary badge!

Tags: discussion

Since what [goes around](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3351/25739) should come around, I'd like to congratulate enderland for being the second person on the site's to obtain the [legendary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary) badge! This significant milestone is awarded for <strike>abusing the HNQ</strike> hitting the daily reputation cap 150 times.

[Legenderland](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33105796#33105796), in your own words: *Thanks for helping make this place great!*

Comment: Congrats, @enderland! You always bring a sense of calm and maturity to a post when you contribute!

Comment: You have been a legend since long. The HNQ just helps make it look official. ;) @enderland

Comment: Well done! And I'll take the opportunity to thank you for doing a great job at moderation as well. You're definitely one of the foundations of the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: It's nice and friendly, but Lightness has a point. Enforce a standard or don't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nice try, you're on meta. See the [tag:discussion] tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a duplicate. Someone else already has the award.

Answer (score 17):

Congratulations!

I have always found your answers to be reasonable, well thought-out, and thought-provoking - not to mention *legendary*.

Keep up the great work.