# Congratulations to Joe Strazzere for 100k... no... 200k rep!

Tags: discussion

[Congratulations to Joe Strazzere for 100k rep!](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/congratulations-to-joe-strazzere-for-100k-rep)

Too early to celebrate, or should we just wait at least 4-7 more days?

It's time, [Light the Beacons!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6LGJ7evrAg#t=54s)

Comment: We are all eagerly waiting for milestone to start the celebrations. However, given that he hasn't actually hit 200k yet, I am voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @MaskedMan To be fair to Frank, Jane started the 100k congratulation question when Joe was 800 reps short of the 100k milestone.

Comment: @Snow My above comment and the close vote was a bit of a joke, looks like I forgot to put a smiley at the end. :)

Comment: 800 reps is 4 days for Joe

Comment: @MaskedMan anyways, "Should ..." questions are also asking for a specific choice so ... ;)

Comment: I'm waiting for the actual 200K then I'll upvote everything in sight, well done Joe!!

Comment: I was going to joke about how he was 563 rep away -- oh, no, wait, I just stumbled across a post of his, now he's 553 away -- but I've apparently already upvoted all of his top posts. Go figure.

Comment: 363 rep left (It's the finaaal count dowwwnn)

Comment: Joe's a Workplace.SE machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Congratulations to Joe Strazzere for 100k rep!](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/congratulations-to-joe-strazzere-for-100k-rep)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Thanks, everyone! I really enjoy reading all the thoughtful questions and answers here at The Workplace.

Comment: I wonder if we have to flag that answer as VLQ as one-liner are not the best way to answer. Please explain why your A will work and how it will be helpful to OP. Once you have enough rep, you'll be able to comment. BTW: what's this *k* right after your 200 rep? just kiddin'!!! Congrats Joe!!! :)))

Comment: Answers are not for asking OP for clarification. Please do that in comments. Congrats stranger.

Comment: Awesome achievement Joe, keep it up, you touch a lot of lives positively (Y)

Comment: Now you have 200k! I hope my 6 votes are not counted as serial upvoting. EDIT: Ah damn, it was detected. Was worth a try.

Comment: @ThorstenS. ...Why would you serially upvote, anyway? Just wander around the popular questions. He's answered most of them.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Which I did...I upvoted them, but the count disappeared after a while, I rechecked by loading. But, moment, hey, now he has 200 000!

Comment: Congrats! Excellent news.

Answer (score 17):

Congratulations officially now!

[image: 200k]

Comment: 14 - 41 badges ... Jackpot? @JoeStrazzere

Comment: @DarkCygnus That's meta badges.  He's got a lot more badges on main, including currently 100 gold badges.

Comment: @gerrit uhmmm, yeah I know Joe has tons of badges on main. I was saying that the fact it was symmetric (14 41), plus clipping exactly 200k seemed like a jackpot to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations. Well deserved.