# Congratulations to Joe Strazzere for breaking the 300K rep barrier!

Tags: discussion

[Congratulations to Joe Strazzere for 100k... no... 200k rep!](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/congratulations-to-joe-strazzere-for-100k-no-200k-rep)
[Congratulations to Joe Strazzere for 100k rep!](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/congratulations-to-joe-strazzere-for-100k-rep)

Congratulations Joe on 300k, a well deserved highscore. All your answers are indicative of deep thinking and a wealth of experience, you set a pretty high standard around here. Plus you stay out of everything except helping people so you're all around a pretty admirable chap.

[image: Joe Strazzere]

Well done!

Answer (score 29):

Thank you! I appreciate the kind words.

Comment: I wonder who the 2 downvotes came from

Comment: @Kilisi - not everyone is a fan I guess! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we should change the workplace logo to be Joe's profile picture and just be done with it!

Thanks for all of your great answers and support for the working community.

Comment: "It's just... good business."